# Searching and counting files in directories and subdirectories [BASH]

Tags: bash, shell

I have one question about searching and counting files in directories and subdirectories. I tried to do something like this

```
for i in $(find $TEST_DIR -type d | wc -l ); do
        for j in $(find $i -type f | wc -l); do
            FILES=$[FILES+j]
        done    
        DIRS=$[DIRS+i]
    done
```

but it doesn't work. I just have to count files in every directory and subdirectory after that I have to compare quantity of files and directories(subdirectories)
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: But I need to find it recursively 'cause if in every directory I have to find if there are only directories or no (if no I have to write a warning message)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `find` command will find all files/dirs recursively, so the `for...loop` is not needed:

```
FILES=$(find $TEST_DIR -type f | wc -l)
DIRS=$(find $TEST_DIR -type d | wc -l)
```

If your filename may contains `newline`, try this:

```
FILES=$(find $TEST_DIR -type f -printf x | wc -c)
```

Comment: This is not 100% correct (but will obviously work most of the time): If a filename contains the newline character (which is allowed in UNIX), it will fail. That one will work better with GNU find: `find "$TEST_DIR" -type f -printf "1\n" | wc -l`

Comment: As an alternative for the newlines: `find "$TEST_DIR" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l`