# why is part of my one liner not being executed

Tags: bash, find

I am trying to write a one liner to find the number of files in each home directory.  I am trying to do this as the other day I had situation where I ran out of inodes on /home.  It took me a long time to find the offender and I want to shorten this process.  This is what i have but it is not working.

```
for i in /home/*; do if [ -d "$i" ]; then cd $i find . -xdev -maxdepth 100 -type f |wc -l; fi done
```

When I run it, it prints a 0 for each home directory, and I remain in roots home directory.

However when I run just this part:

```
for i in /home/*; do if [ -d "$i" ]; then cd $i; fi done
```

I wind up in the last home directory leading me to believe I traversed them all.

And when I run this in each users home directory:

```
find . -xdev -maxdepth 100 -type f |wc -l
```

I get a legit answer.

Comment: are you missing a && after cd $i? also see other questions on SO, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839055/searching-and-counting-files-in-directories-and-subdirectories-bash or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216370/how-to-count-number-of-files-in-each-directory

Comment: missing `;` after `cd $i`??

Comment: Or just remove the `cd` altogeather (not best practice to have it in a shell script anyway) and put the path in your find. Also, why are you putting this as a "one liner"?

Comment: Thanks @BroSlow so In the future if i need it in can just paste it in to the command line on any of the hundreds of servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a terminating character after your `cd`. But more importantly, using `cd` can cause unwanted errors if you're not careful, try below instead (`cd` not needed).

```
for i in /home/*; do [ -d "$i" ] && echo "$i" && find "$i" -xdev -maxdepth 100 -type f | wc -l;  done
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `find` can take multiple paths, you don't need a loop:

```
find /home/*/ -xdev -maxdepth 100 -type f | wc -l
```

To avoid any issues with filenames containing newlines (rare, yes), you can take advantage of an additional GNU extension to `find` (you're using `-maxdepth`, so I assume you can use `-printf` as well):

```
find /home/*/ -xdev -maxdepth 100 -type f -printf "." | wc -c
```

Since you aren't actually using the name of the file for counting, replace it with a single-character string, then count the length of the resulting string.

Comment: yours does not give the file count for the individual directories only the total files